# No funciona el scroll en aplicación Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, scroll

Soy nuevo en programación `Android` y tengo el siguiente problema:

Estoy desarrollando una App que muestra información en 3 listas (categorías). Para esto implemente una `TabBar` (Que viene por defecto en Android), que maneja un `fragment`, a este `fragment` le paso una lista de objetos (que parseo desde un archivo `Json`) que tiene la información y es mostrada a través de un `ListView`.

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Cuando corro la aplicación en cada pestaña el `scroll` no funciona correctamente, no puedo bajar para ver mas elementos de la Lista y no se cual puede ser el error.

Gracias por su atención.

Método `onCreate`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}
```

`Fragment` que uso para mostrar mi información:

```
public class fragmentList extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public fragmentList() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static fragmentList newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        fragmentList fragment = new fragmentList();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listaMultas);
        String json = loadJSONFromAssets("datos.json");

        final List<Multa> multasLeves = convertJSONToObjects(json, 1);
        final List<Multa> multasGraves = convertJSONToObjects(json, 2);
        final List<Multa> multasMuyGraves = convertJSONToObjects(json, 3);

        ListViewAdapter adapterList = null;

        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
            case 1:
                adapterList = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, multasLeves);
                listView.setAdapter(adapterList);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click en " + multasLeves.get(position).getCodigo(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        AlertDialog dialog = createDialog(multasLeves.get(position));
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                });
                break;

            case 2:
                adapterList = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, multasGraves);
                listView.setAdapter(adapterList);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                        AlertDialog dialog = createDialog(multasGraves.get(position));
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                });
                break;

            case 3:
                adapterList = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, multasMuyGraves);
                listView.setAdapter(adapterList);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                        AlertDialog dialog = createDialog(multasMuyGraves.get(position));
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                });
                break;
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    public List<Multa> convertJSONToObjects(String json, int tipo) {
        List<Multa> objetos = new ArrayList<Multa>();
        String calificacion = null;

        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
            if(tipo == 1) calificacion = "leves";
            if(tipo == 2) calificacion = "graves";
            if(tipo == 3) calificacion = "muy_graves";
            JSONArray json_array = obj.optJSONArray(calificacion);

            for (int i = 0; i < json_array.length(); i++) {
                objetos.add(new Multa(json_array.getJSONObject(i)));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return objetos;
    }

    public String loadJSONFromAssets(String nombre) {
        String json = null;

        try {
            AssetManager am = getActivity().getAssets();
            InputStream is = am.open(nombre);
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }

        return json;
    }

    public AlertDialog createDialog(Multa multa) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setTitle(multa.getCodigo())
                .setMessage(multa.getInfraccion())
                .setNegativeButton("CERRAR",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            }
                        }).setCancelable(true);

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Adaptador del `ListView`:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private List<Multa> multas;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int layout, List<Multa> multas){
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.multas = multas;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.multas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.multas.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View rootView = convertView;

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null);

        Multa currentMulta = multas.get(position);
        TextView codigo = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewCodigo);
        TextView descripcion = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewDescripcion);

        codigo.setText(currentMulta.getCodigo());
        descripcion.setText(currentMulta.getInfraccion());

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

`Fragment xml` con la lista

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="layout.fragmentList">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listaMultas"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Si se necesita mas inforación que la brindada por favor comentemenlo, Gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: muestra tu xml donde se encuentra la lista please

Comment: si el xml es lo que necesitamos ver tambien

Comment: @FabioVenturiPastor , ya edite la pregunta amigos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se supone que el listView crea su propio scroll dependiendo de la longitud de tu arreglo, cuando ve que son muchos datos lo crea de lo contrario no, pero en mi experiencia te puedo decir que despues de el RelativeLayout crea un LinearLayout. Ejemplo:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_picture"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.tritonix.scotproyect.PictureActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/listaMultas"/>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Probé lo que me dijiste amigo, y funciona; el problema es que el fragment es muy pequeñito y no ocupa toda la pantalla a pesar que esta con match_parent

Comment: Si checalo a mi me funciono pero yo tengo un GridView en vez de un ListView. Saludos

Comment: Mi fragment se queda diminuto

Answer (score -1):

Necesitas modificar el Layout que utiliza el fragment para que sea Scrollable, probablemente estas utilizando un LinearLayout o un RelativeLayout, para hacer esto tienes que ir al código XML del fragment, se debería de llamar algo asi como "fragment_fragmentList" y encerrar todo tu código XML con lo siguiente:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    //Tu codigo XML aquí

   </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Cuando hago el scrollView, queda de tamaño pequeño, no obedece al match_parent, pero funciona.

Comment: Si te das cuenta en el código que te pase esta definido android:layout_height="wrap_content" eso significa que la altura de este Layout dependerá de los elementos que contiene dentro, para que coincida con el match_parent tendrás que cambiar esos dos atributos y poner match_parent. Una cosa que tambien me he dado cuenta por lo menos en Android Studio es que para poder diseñar partes del Layout (que no se ven en la pantalla) tendrás que aumentar el tamaño de la pantalla para que lo puedas ver.